# java, alguna alternativa al uso de extends?

Tags: java, herencia

primera pregunta, es posible que esta conteste mi duda principal: si yo en una clase pongo:

`public class c1 extends JPanel{...}` entiendo que estoy heredando todos los metodos de la jerarquia JPanel, pero si yo hago

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class c1{
JPanel JP1 = new JPanel();}
```

de esta forma también se están heredando todos los métodos?

en particular estoy intentando pintar un rectángulo, ya tengo mi `JFrame` hecho como la segunda forma que puse, también mi `jpanel` y lo agrego al `jframe`, también esta el método `llenaJPanel` ya que no estoy usando constructores, pero tengo problemas al llamar el método `paintcomponent(Graphics g)` ya que no puedo hacer esto:
`JP1.paintComponent(Graphics g)` por que no lo reconoce, y si escribo : `paintComponent(Graphics g)` lo toma como un método mio y no como un método heredado de la clase `JComponent`, y no se que hacer.

espero se entienda, gracias

Comment: Puedes usar la palabra `super.paintComponent(Graphics)` para llamar al método padre

Comment: Si ver tu código no acabo de entender el error. Por cierto, es muy rara la ocasión en la que uno tiene que llamar a `paintComponent`, es un método que Swing se encarga de llamar cuando lo considera oportuno.

Comment: no funciono, recuerden quiero evitar usar el extends JPanel o cualquier derivado, ya use import javax.swing.*; y aun asi, al intentar poner dentro de un metodo cualquiera la palabra super.paintComponent, no lo reconoce.